# Hover on SmartGWT FormItem title

Tags: hover, smartgwt

How to hover on or how to control hover on exactly the FormItem title in SmartGWT?
I am trying to show text on hovering on FormItem title, but the hover is starting in the blank spaces of the formitem rather than on the title. Clueless about as to how to hover exactly on the formitem title.

Thanks a lot for the response, below is the code I am working on :

```
    String fieldDesc = detailsRecord.getAttribute("ATTR_LANG_DESC");
    String example = detailsRecord.getAttribute("ATTR_LANG_EX_CNT");
    String network = detailsRecord.getAttribute("PUBLICATION_TYPE");
    String gdsnName = detailsRecord.getAttribute("ATTR_GDSN_NAME");

    String INFOTEXT = "";

    INFOTEXT =  "<span><b>Definition: </b>"+fieldDesc+"</span>"+
                "<span><br/><br><b>GDSN Tag: </b>"+gdsnName+"</span>"+
                "<span><br/><br><b>Example: </b>"+example+"</span>";
    //if network is not empty
    if(network!=null && !network.equals(EMPTY_STRING)){
        INFOTEXT= INFOTEXT+"<span><br/><br/><b>Network: </b>"+network+"</span>";
    }

    formItem.setHoverWidth(450);
    formItem.setHoverHeight(50);

    final String INFOTEXT_FINAL = INFOTEXT;

    formItem.setItemTitleHoverFormatter(new FormItemHoverFormatter() {
        public String getHoverHTML(FormItem item, DynamicForm form) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return INFOTEXT_FINAL;
        }
    });
```

Here I am trying to hover just on Item title but this is not working. Please find the screen shot to get a better idea as to what I mean to convey.
As you can see from the picture the hover is occurs in the empty spaces of the InfoProvider field. I need to make it exactly on the FormItem title, please let me know if I am clear. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Show some code.. some images of what do you want to do or what are you getting?

Comment: @RAS thank you, please find the above code and the image in the hyperlink SmartGWTFormItemHoverIssue.

Comment: Try using `formItem.setHoverAlign(Alignment.CENTER);`

Comment: @RAS thank you for the response, but the setHoverAlign API is for the actual text alignment that is displayed within the tooltip. My problem is to show the tooltip if and if only the hover is on the formitem title.

Comment: Try applying custom css to control the look of tooltip by using `formItem.setHoverStyle()`

Comment: @RAS, again this will affect only the way the tooltipis styled, but this will not be able to prevent to stop hovering all over the  formitem rather than on exactly the title, by the way i tried style hover as well. The basic problem is with limiting the hover to the title. Anyway i appreciate your response. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what the problem is that the FormItem canvas is much bigger than it looks. So when you create formItem for infoProvider and add it to the overlay, the canvas extends the entire width of the overlay, with the title using the first space.
[image]

If you really only want to see the 'hover' over the title text, I think one solution would be to use a Label that is exactly as wide as the title text and to turn the formItem's title off(setShowTitle(false)). You could then use SpacerItems or tweak the layout so that it still looks the same.